# Elastic4s Scripts, Partial Update

Tags: scala, groovy, elasticsearch, playframework, elastic4s

I'm trying to update a document by adding/updating an array of objects, using `client.execute { update ... }`, but I'm having issues trying to pass in key value pairs in Elastic4s. I can't find any documentation on `ctx._source`, except for [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html) which says nothing.

```
val store_reservation_response_future = client.execute {

    update(ota_id) in "rsconfig/ota" script "ctx._source.developers =
    [key]" params(Map("key" -> "value"))

}
```

The preceding code puts the following in the db:

> "developers": [ "value" ]

I tried:

```
params(Map("key" -> (Map("key1" -> "value"))))
```

But I get the following error:

> background log: error: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't write type [class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1]

How do I add a key value pair?

I found a [java solution](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/133sq31fsm/java-api-update-append-to-object-array), but it did not help me.

If there is any documentation someone can point me to, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you try converting the map to a java map before using it ?

Comment: I'm trying to stick strictly to Scala.

Comment: Yes but sometimes you need to use java collections to interface with things that are based on Java, as elastic4s is. If you try it, and it works, then I can add special support to elastic4s to do the conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized who is writing these comments. I will update you once I try it out.